# Rename the property in json serialization

Tags: asp.net, json, serialization

In [Json.net](http://json.codeplex.com) we can rename the property with `[JsonPropertyAttribute("")]` ,

```
public class Foo {
 public string Foo1 { set; get; }
 public string Foo2 { set; get; }
}
```

and in the web service code behind:

```
[WebMethod]
public List <Foo> GetFoos() {
 List <Foo> post = new List < Foo > {
  new Foo(),
  new Foo(),
  new Foo()
 };
 return post;
}
```

How can I rename the Foo1 property name to F1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example if you use `DataContractJsonSerializer` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx) you can declare following

```
[DataContract(Name = "User")]
struct Person
{
   [DataMember(Name = "FirstName")]
   public string Name;

   [DataMember(Name = "LastName")]
   public string Surname;
}
```